# How can I merge consecutive subArrays which have the same data in it?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge, associative-array

I have this array:

```
$opening_hours = array(
  'Monday' => array('09:00', '17:00'),
  'Tuesday' => array('09:00', '17:00'),
  'Wednesday' => array('08:00', '13:00'), 
  'Thursday' => array('09:00', '17:00'),
  'Friday' => array('09:00', '17:00'),
  'Saturday' => array('10:00', '16:00'),
  'Sunday' => array('Closed'),
);
```

I need to somehow merge those opening hours to the array which should look like this:

```
$merged_opening_hours = array(
  'Monday - Tuesday' => array('09:00', '17:00'),
  'Wednesday' => array('08:00', '13:00'),
  'Thursday - Friday' => array('09:00', '17:00'),
  'Saturday' => array('10:00', '16:00');
  'Sunday' => array('Closed'),
);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: @FrancescoAbeni I've tried to loop through $opening_hours array and I was checking if next element of an array is the same as the current one, but somehow this didn't work. Rizier123 did it exacly what I need with explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work for you:

So basically you just loop through your entire array and check if the next element is still set AND the current array is the same as the next one (Which means they have the same hours). If yes you do this until the while loop returns false. Which is this code:

```
$DayAmountOfConsecutiveSameHours = 1;
while(isset($arrayKeys[($dayCount+$DayAmountOfConsecutiveSameHours)]) && 
     ($opening_hours[$arrayKeys[$dayCount]] === $opening_hours[$arrayKeys[($dayCount+$DayAmountOfConsecutiveSameHours)]]))
    $DayAmountOfConsecutiveSameHours++;
```

Then if you have more than 1 entry you create a range from one to the other day. Which is this code:

```
if($DayAmountOfConsecutiveSameHours > 1)
    $result[$arrayKeys[$dayCount] . " - " . $arrayKeys[($dayCount+$DayAmountOfConsecutiveSameHours-1)]] = $opening_hours[$arrayKeys[$dayCount]];
```

If you only have 1 day with the same hours you just add it to the results array. Which is this code:

```
else
    $result[$arrayKeys[$dayCount]] = $opening_hours[$arrayKeys[$dayCount]];
```

And according to how many days the same hours have you skip the next array elements. Which is this code:

```
$dayCount += ($DayAmountOfConsecutiveSameHours - 1);
```

Full code:

```
<?php

    $opening_hours = [
            "Monday" => ["09:00", "17:00"],
            "Tuesday" => ["09:00", "17:00"],
            "Wednesday" => ["08:00", "13:00"], 
            "Thursday" => ["09:00", "17:00"],
            "Friday" => ["09:00", "17:00"],
            "Saturday" => ["10:00", "16:00"],
            "Sunday" => ["Closed"],
        ];


    $amountOfDays = count($opening_hours);
    $arrayKeys = array_keys($opening_hours);

    for($dayCount = 0; $dayCount < $amountOfDays; $dayCount++) {
        $DayAmountOfConsecutiveSameHours = 1;
        while(isset($arrayKeys[($dayCount+$DayAmountOfConsecutiveSameHours)]) && ($opening_hours[$arrayKeys[$dayCount]] === $opening_hours[$arrayKeys[($dayCount+$DayAmountOfConsecutiveSameHours)]]))
            $DayAmountOfConsecutiveSameHours++;

        if($DayAmountOfConsecutiveSameHours > 1)
            $result[$arrayKeys[$dayCount] . " - " . $arrayKeys[($dayCount+$DayAmountOfConsecutiveSameHours-1)]] = $opening_hours[$arrayKeys[$dayCount]];
        else
            $result[$arrayKeys[$dayCount]] = $opening_hours[$arrayKeys[$dayCount]];

        $dayCount += ($DayAmountOfConsecutiveSameHours - 1);
    }

    print_r($result);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [Monday - Tuesday] => Array
        (
            [0] => 09:00
            [1] => 17:00
        )

    [Wednesday] => Array
        (
            [0] => 08:00
            [1] => 13:00
        )

    [Thursday - Friday] => Array
        (
            [0] => 09:00
            [1] => 17:00
        )

    [Saturday] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10:00
            [1] => 16:00
        )

    [Sunday] => Array
        (
            [0] => Closed
        )

)
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](https://eval.in/397153)

Comment: Thank you for the explanations and whole function. It does work like it should. Before asking this question I've started with comparing next element of an array with the current one in my case it didn't work. Thnak you again.

Comment: @David updated my answer and simplified everything a bit. Hopes it makes it easier to understand