# Join days of the week based on value

Tags: php, arrays

I have a form that allows users to enter the time they worked from Monday to Sunday.

For example a user can enter the following:

```
Monday: 8am to 5pm
Tuesday: 8am to 5pm
Weds: 10am to 12pm
Thursday: 8am to 5pm
Friday: 8am to 5pm
Saturday: None
Sunday: None
```

I have this data in an array `$office` and the weekdays as key for the work hours.

Now I'm trying to merge days, which follow each other, with the same work hours, so I can output the data like this:

```
Monday - Tuesday: 8am to 5pm
Weds: 10am to 12pm
Thursday - Friday: 8am to 5pm
Saturday - Sunday: None
```

Right now I'm trying to do this with a lot and big if/else statements, where I check each combination of days if they have the same work hours.

A little snippet from it, so you get an idea what I tried:

```
<?php

    $monday = $office['monday'];
    $tuesday = $office['tuesday'];
    $wednesday = $office['wednesday'];
    $thursday = $office['thursday'];
    $friday = $office['friday'];
    $saturday = $office['saturday'];
    $sunday = $office['sunday'];


    if($monday == $tuesday && $monday == $wednesday && $monday == $thursday && $monday == $friday && $monday == $saturday && $monday == $sunday){
        echo "<li><strong>Monday - Sunday</strong>: {$monday}</li>";
    } elseif($monday == $tuesday && $monday == $wednesday && $monday == $thursday && $monday == $friday && $monday == $saturday){
        echo "<li><strong>Monday - Saturday</strong>: {$monday}</li>";
        echo "<li><strong>Sunday</strong>: {$sunday}</li>";
    }

    //... All combinations of days with the same work hours

    } else{
        echo "<li><strong>Monday</strong>: {$monday}</li>";
        echo "<li><strong>Tuesday</strong>: {$tuesday}</li>";
        echo "<li><strong>Wednesday</strong>: {$wednesday}</li>";
        echo "<li><strong>Thursday</strong>: {$thursday}</li>";
        echo "<li><strong>Friday</strong>: {$friday}</li>";
        echo "<li><strong>Saturday</strong>: {$saturday}</li>";
        echo "<li><strong>Sunday</strong>: {$sunday}</li>";
    }
```

Now I hope and wondering if there is a easier/cleaner way to do this? Maybe a PHP function or some smaller and cleaner code than what I have right now?

Comment: How your data is stored in db?

Comment: Can you post the code you are currently using, so we can see how we can help?

Comment: As the above comments already pointed out you need to clarify your question a bit more. Do you have this data in a db? in an array? as a string? Show us your current code.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31370181/3933332

Comment: @Rizier123 That question is exactly what i am looking for. I just didn't know how to word it properly. I should have pasted my code example as well but it was huge with me trying to filter through the days. I just knew i wasn't doing it right and didn't explain it right. Sorry but thank you for finding this.

Comment: @jAC You're welcome. If the code was huge and pretty repetitive you could have just shown how it looks and cut it off with a `//...` so we see in which form you have the data, how you get the data, and where you are stuck. So we can exactly explain and show you how to get to the solution. But I'm happy we found the Q&A which answers your question.

Comment: Yeah, i'm still very new posting here but this community has been a great help. I will get better with my posts and learn from my mistakes. Thanks again!

Comment: @jAC If you want you can post your code as a pastebin link here and I will edit it into the question, so you can see how you could have done it + we can improve your question.

Comment: Actually @Rizier123 your code from the link you sent me works without me changing a thing. If you want to post that as the answer here it was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @jAC If another Q&A answered your question, then it's a duplicate for that post and the answer shouldn't be posted twice. But your question here is still useful! See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844 under "Should duplicates be deleted?". As I mentioned in the above comment you can post a pastebin link to your code and I can edit it into the question.

Comment: @Rizier123 Pastebin added to show my example. The solution was to use your code from that other post. I made it a function so I can use it later if need be.

Comment: @jAC Now we got your question into a good shape and has already been reopen and closed with the appropriate dupe ;)