# Want to show opening hours dynamically in php

Tags: php, arrays, database

Hi i want to show Opening hours which i'm getting dynamically through database. here is the array of that

```
  Array
(
    [from] => Array
        (
            [0] => 09:30
            [1] => 09:30
            [2] => 09:30
            [3] => 09:30
            [4] => 09:30
            [5] => 09:30
            [6] => 09:30
        )

    [to] => Array
        (
            [0] => 18:30
            [1] => 18:30
            [2] => 18:30
            [3] => 18:30
            [4] => 18:30
            [5] => 18:30
            [6] => 18:30
        )

)
```

Now what i want is if the time is equals to fri then it will show the time `Mon-Fri` and then `Sat Sun closed` or if the time is same till Saturday then it will show Mon-Sat and if the whole week time is same then it will show `Mon-Sun`. Hope i am able to tell you exactly what i want. This is my PHP code

**Updated Answer**

```
 $result = array_unique($time['from']);
if (count(array_unique($time['from'])) == 3)
 {
    echo '<li><strong>Mon-Fri:</strong><span>' . $time['from'] . ' to ' .  $time['to'] . '</span></li>
        <li>
          <strong>Sat-Sun:</strong>
          <span>'. $time['from'][6] .'</span>
        </li>';
 } else if(count(array_unique($time['from'])) == 2) 
 {
   echo '<li><strong>Mon-sat:</strong><span>' . $time['from'][0] . ' to ' . $time['to'][0] . '</span></li>
    <li>
      <strong>Sun:</strong>
      <span>'. $time['from'][6] .'</span>
    </li>';
 }
else if(count(array_unique($time['from'])) == 1) {
    echo '<li><strong>Mon - Sun:</strong><span>' . $time['from'][0] . ' to ' . $time['to'][0] . '</span></li>';
                        }
```

Comment: Do you mean, if the time for mon-fri is the same, just output it as one time? The [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)  function may be helpful.

Comment: Yes this is what i mean, Ok i'll try this

Comment: Hey am i using it in right way this is how i am printing it `echo'<pre>';
       $resultaa = $time['from'];
       print_r(array_diff($resultaa));
       echo'</pre>';`

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31370181/3933332 . I don't really see what your full data structure is. Is the shown array the entire array and just each time represents each day in the week?