# Merge identical array values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
$storeArray = array('Monday' => '08:30 - 16:30',
                    'Tuesday' => '08:30 - 15:30',
                    'Wednesday' => 08:30 - 16:30',
                    'Thursday' => 08:30 - 16:30',
                    'Friday' => 14:30 - 13:30',
                    'Saturday' => 14:30 - 13:30',
                    'Sunday' => 10:00 - 15:30'
              );
```

Now I want to merge all identical array values and print the array like this:

```
Monday - Wednesday - Thursday : 08:30 - 16:30
Tuesday : 08:30 - 15:30
Friday - Saturday: 14:30 - 13:30
Sunday: 10:00 - 15:30
```

Comment: why isn't monday merged with wednesday and thurs? and where's the code you're working with?

Comment: Sorry updated question

Comment: Very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31370181

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is just to group and flip it. Reassign the values by grouping them, after they are all grouped (meaning all the times), flip the grouped array.

Idea:

```
// group
$datetime = array();
foreach ($storeArray as $day => $time) {
    $datetime[$time][] = $day;
}
// and
// implode flip
$datetime = array_flip(array_map(function($e){
    return implode(' - ', $e);
}, $datetime));
```

And that should yield something like this:

```
Array
(
    [Monday - Wednesday - Thursday] => 08:30 - 16:30
    [Tuesday] => 08:30 - 15:30
    [Friday - Saturday] => 14:30 - 13:30
    [Sunday] => 10:00 - 15:30
)
```

Now you can do what you will.

Another version, same result:

```
// container, total count, counter
$datetime = array(); $len = count($storeArray); $i = 0;
foreach ($storeArray as $day => $time) {
    if (!isset($datetime[$time])) {
        $datetime[$time] = ''; // initialize
    }
    $datetime[$time] .= $day . ' - '; // concatenate dash
    if ($i == ($len - 1)) { // at the end of the loop, make cosmetic changes, remove extra dash
        // remove each extra dash, then flip
        $datetime = array_flip(array_map(function($e){ return rtrim($e, ' - '); }, $datetime));
    }
    $i++; // counter
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ghost. It's perfect

Comment: Monday - Tuesday - Wednesday - Thursday - Friday: 11:00 am - 10:00 pm. So can we print Monday - Friday: 11:00 am - 10:00 pm? @Ghost

Comment: If same value then use 1st & last key

Comment: @Ghost Another version, same result: https://3v4l.org/4rn0B :) Good answer!